# Javascript - Run my script only if landscape is detected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a script to show a notification within a menu with scroll, but I do not know how to detect if the device has **orientation landscape to validate the script**.

The call `onClick="VerHayMas();"` works perfectly, but if the user open the menu once, clicking on `#boton-menu` and with your device in portrait, after changing the orientation to landscape the script no longer meet the objective.

> The script has its logic ONLY if the device is in landscape, which is
>   when the menu needs to show the notification.

So, is it possible that my script is only valid with `(max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape)`, ignoring the portrait...?

I am a beginner in JS, and I do not know how to do it, really.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

**HTML & CSS**

```
#mas-menu {display:none}

<div id="boton-menu" onClick="VerHayMas();">+</div>
```

**Script:**

```
var clicksVerHayMas = 0;

function VerHayMas() {
    clicksVerHayMas = clicksVerHayMas + 1;
    if (clicksVerHayMas == 1) {
        document.getElementById('mas-menu').style.display = 'block';

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('#mas-menu').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 4000);
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried with the following script, but it does not work. If the user makes a call to `onClick="VerHayMas();"` in portrait mode, the script is no longer running in landscape mode.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
const matchesMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape)').matches;

if (matchesMediaQuery) {

var clicksVerHayMas = 0;
  function VerHayMas() {
  clicksVerHayMas = clicksVerHayMas +1;
  if(clicksVerHayMas == 1){
  document.getElementById('mas-menu').style.display = 'block';

  window.setTimeout(function(){
  $('#mas-menu').fadeOut('slow');
  },4000);
  }};
}
```

Comment: You can get the width and height of a window with `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` respectively. How about keep it simple, if height is less than width, the user is in landscape mode.

Comment: If you simply want to hide something on landscape orientation, why not use one line of CSS?

Comment: Your attempt at putting the function declaration inside the `if` statement does not work because then it is no longer a global that can be called from the inline event handler attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this using [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```
const matchesMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape)').matches;

if (matchesMediaQuery) {
    // do something
}
```

Make sure to note the browser support in the MDN link.

**EDIT TO PROVIDE CONTEXT:**

Because the user may be moving around their screen, you will want to make this evaluation *inside* `VerHayMas`, each time it is run, to determine if the main body of the script should be executed:

```
var clicksVerHayMas = 0;

function VerHayMas() {
    var isLandscapeAndMeetsSizeRequirements = window.matchMedia('(max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape)').matches;

    if (isLandscapeAndMeetsSizeRequirements) {
        clicksVerHayMas = clicksVerHayMas + 1;
        if (clicksVerHayMas == 1) {
            document.getElementById('mas-menu').style.display = 'block';

            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('#mas-menu').fadeOut('slow');
            }, 4000);
        }
    }
};
```

So `VerHayMas` will be run on every click, but only if the screen meets the requirements as determined by the media query string will it execute the code inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 10):

I'd keep it simple, if screen height is less than width, then the user is in landscape mode. You can grab the height and width from the  global [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object.

```
if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
    // The user is in landscape mode!
    userInLanscapeFunc();
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use `screen.width`/`.height` though it depends if they actually care about the shape of the available window area or the screen orientation