# how to create a function that work in specific width in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

is it possible to create a function in javascript or jquery that work in specific width in CSS
like I want to create a button that alert("hello world") but this will work only on mobile screen in other media queries will do nothing

Comment: I don’t understand what this has to do with CSS or whether the device is mobile. Do you just want the button to be visible on all viewport widths but only to do something if the viewport width is less than a certain size?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of [Javascript - Run my script only if landscape is detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978407/javascript-run-my-script-only-if-landscape-is-detected).  For what it is worth, although my answer did not receive the most votes it did get the user's choice, and, like @zero298 's suggestion, I recommended leveraging [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) -- if you want JS triggering on the basis of media queries this is the most native approach you can take, in my opinion.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, You can use the following code to get the width:

```
// Size of browser viewport.
$(window).width();

// Size of HTML document (same as pageHeight/pageWidth in screenshot).
$(document).width();
```

so if you want to apply on mobile, you can add a condition

```
if ($(window).width() <= 425) {
   // Do something
   alert("hello world")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(window).width() < 768){
  // do something
}
```

if using jquery

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 575) {
        alert("hello world")
        }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```